# not sure why I am getting an empty outputstream from httpurlconnection

Tags: java

I have the following code:

```
try {
            URL url = new URL(webPage);
            try {
                is = new FileInputStream(new File("testfiles/test.html"));
                byte[] buffer = new byte[is.available()];
                int tb = is.read(buffer);
                System.out.println(tb);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            con.setDoOutput(true);


            con.setRequestProperty(authorizationHeaderName, authorizationHeaderValue);
            con.setRequestMethod("POST");
            con.setRequestProperty("ACCEPT", "application/hal+json");
            OutputStream os = con.getOutputStream();
            System.out.println(os);
            System.out.println(is);
            int bytesCopied = IOUtils.copy(is,  os);

            os.close();
            is.close();
```

But when I copy my fileInputStream into the OutputStream it comes up with 0 bytes. I checked the size of my output from con.getOutputStream(); and it appears there is no object there. The System.out.println is coming back blank - is there a way to get an outputstream on the httpsUrlConnection class?

Comment: `System.out.println(os);` <- you can not just print streams like this.

Comment: I was just trying to prove the object was there, and it wasn't. When I wrap it like this DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream()); the println gives me back an object. But the copy still doesn't work. I just want to copy the data from my fileinputstream into the outputstream of my httpsurlconnection.

Answer (score 0):

From what I know you need to use methods like `.read()` to read from your file and `.write()`to write to the other file path.

Comment: I think my try catch was making a local variable for my class. I was able to copy the stream once I fixed that, but I am still not able to get the stream back once my con.getResponseCode(); is called. I cannot read the output stream after I am finished.

Comment: I solved my problem, I was not passing a correct content-type. But this was not the answer to my problem, so no check.